# No solutions work for my wamp server error: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in D\...\class-wp-http-curl.php on line 239

Tags: php, wordpress, wampserver

I have been trying to import WordPress  theme unit test data via the WordPress importer but every time I get the following error:

**Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in D:\Essentials\wamp\www\treehouse\wp-includes\class-wp-http-curl.php on line 239.**

I have already tried the following:

1. Edited **php.ini** fie in my wamp server and set the **max_execution_time
   to 3000 and also set the  max_input_time to 3000.** *Restarted wamp
   before trying again.*
2. Used ' **WP Maximum Execution Time Exceeded** ' **plugin** which writes to the
   .htaccess file. *Restarted wamp before trying again.*
3. Edited **phpmyadmin.conf** in ' \wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf ' and set the
   following values as below:

   php_admin_value max_execution_time 3600 
   php_admin_value max_input_time 3600

They were set to 360 before.
*Restarted wamp before trying again.*

None of the above procedures seems to solvethe fatal error. **Every time the max execution time is 60 seconds, not 120, not anything else.**

Comment: Have you tried adding  `php_admin_value max_execution_time 3600` in the .htaccess file?

Comment: I did that but it didn't help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 php.ini files.

One in `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}\php.ini` this is ued ONLY when you run the PHP CLI.

And one in `\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin\php.ini` which is actually a SYMLINK/JUNCTION to a file called `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}\phpForApache.ini` which is used by PHP when running under Apache.

Anyway the correct way to ensure you edit the correct file used by PHP under Apache is to use the wampmanager menus like this

```
(left click) wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

THis will open the default editor on the correct file.

Change `max_execution_time` in that file, restart Apache and you shoudl be fine.

### After your comment

Then I would look for a `php.ini` file in the wrong place.

In WAMPServer the `php.ini` file should only exist in the `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}` folder and the `\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin` folder although in later versions of WAMPServer the file in `\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin` is actually a junction file (SYMLINK)

Also there should be no reference to the php folder on your PATH so check that also.

Also search you boot disk for any `php.ini` files, if any exists outside the `\wamp\` folder structure remove them. Some bad advice sometimes suggest copying things into `windows\system32` but this is a bad idea in WAMPServer

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly where i went to edit the php.ini file but didn't help.

Comment: See my additional suggestions

Comment: Looked for any other php.ini file but didn't find any. Also I didn't understand what you meant by " Also there should be no reference to the php folder on your PATH so check that also. "

Comment: The WINDOWS PATH environment variable

Comment: Thanks again. Just to inform you I am getting this new error: Notice: wp_get_http is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.4.0! Use WP_Http instead. in D:\Essentials\wamp\www\treehouse\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3706  , I don't know what caused it, if you could help.

Comment: No. Still the same error in addition with the new one.